# How do I convert numpy array to the form ((value0, row0, column0), (value1, row0, column1)...)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to convert numpy array to form such as `((value0, row0, column0), (value1, row0, column1)...)`? e.g. if the input is

```
a = np.array([[10, 15],
              [20, 25]])
```

The output should be:
`((10, 0, 0), (15, 0, 1), (20, 1, 0), (25, 1, 1))`. Moreover, this function should be able to be applied to constants, 1D, 3D, 4D, etc. arrays, e.g. for 4D the output should be (value0, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4). I can create such a function only for a specific dimensionality, e.g. only for 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one for n-dim arrays based on [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) -

```
def stack_indices(a):
    i = np.moveaxis(np.indices(a.shape),0,-1)
    return np.concatenate((a[...,None],i),axis=-1)
```

Sample runs -

`1D` :

```
In [70]: a = np.array([4,5,2])

In [71]: stack_indices(a)
Out[71]: 
array([[4, 0],
       [5, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

`2D` :

```
In [62]: a
Out[62]: 
array([[10, 15, 17],
       [20, 25, 30]])

In [63]: stack_indices(a)
Out[63]: 
array([[[10,  0,  0],
        [15,  0,  1],
        [17,  0,  2]],

       [[20,  1,  0],
        [25,  1,  1],
        [30,  1,  2]]])
```

`3D` :

```
In [68]: a
Out[68]: 
array([[[51, 67],
        [45, 21],
        [56, 92]],

       [[10, 24],
        [63, 22],
        [52, 94]]])

In [69]: stack_indices(a)
Out[69]: 
array([[[[51,  0,  0,  0],
         [67,  0,  0,  1]],

        [[45,  0,  1,  0],
         [21,  0,  1,  1]],

        [[56,  0,  2,  0],
         [92,  0,  2,  1]]],


       [[[10,  1,  0,  0],
         [24,  1,  0,  1]],

        [[63,  1,  1,  0],
         [22,  1,  1,  1]],

        [[52,  1,  2,  0],
         [94,  1,  2,  1]]]])
```

#### Benchmarking

Other posted approaches :

```
from itertools import product

# @Quang Hoang's soln
def prod(a):
    return [(u,)+ v for u,v in zip(a.ravel(), product(*[np.arange(x) for x in a.shape]) )]
    
# @Andy L.'s soln
def ravel(a):
    return [z for z in zip(a.ravel(), *np.unravel_index(np.arange(a.size), a.shape))]
```

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
import benchit
funcs = [stack_indices, prod, ravel]
in_ = [np.random.randint(10,100,([5]*n)) for n in range(1,10)]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_, indexby='shape')
t.rank()
t.plot(logx=False, save='timings.png', rot=90)
```

[image]

To gain better performance on higher-dim arrays, I suppose one could look into array-assignment.

Comment: Nice solution. The only thing I would add is `x = x.reshape(-1, x.shape[-1])` to the end of the function to make the output in the form I want

Comment: I really like the simplicity of `benchit`. How does it compare against `perfplot` ?

Comment: @AndyL. Well `perfplot` worked for me for sometime. But, I figured I want something simple, especially on the setting up and customized for arrays and dataframes, hence that argument `indexby` you would see. So, you certainly got the essence of it :) `benchit` doesn't have those advanced tools of asserting equalities tho .. yet.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to flatten `a` and pair with `meshgrid` or `product` of the indices:

```
a = np.array([[10, 15, 12],
              [20, 25, 13]])

[(u,)+ v for u,v in zip(a.ravel(), product(*[np.arange(x) for x in a.shape]) )]
```

Output:

```
[(10, 0, 0), (15, 0, 1), (12, 0, 2), (20, 1, 0), (25, 1, 1), (13, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: I think I prefer a more explicit approach: `rows, cols = a.shape ; values = ((a[r][j], r, j) for r in range(rows) for j in range(cols))`

Comment: @DeepSpace that wouldn't work for `3D, 4D,...` arrays as requested in the question.

Comment: Indeed... I do wonder what OP meant that it should work for constant as well...

Comment: There is an error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. I used `from numpy import product`. numpy version: 19.2

Comment: @samtestsam `from itertools import product`.

Answer (score 2):

use `zip` with `unravel_index`

```
arr = [z for z in zip(a.ravel(), *np.unravel_index(np.arange(a.size), a.shape))]
```

A more concise code is:

```
arr = list(zip(a.ravel(), *np.unravel_index(np.arange(a.size),a.shape)))

Out[582]: [(10, 0, 0), (15, 0, 1), (12, 0, 2), (20, 1, 0), (25, 1, 1), (13, 1, 2
)]
```